# What am I doing wrong with my own alias in ~/.bash_aliases?

Tags: bash, shell, alias

### `~/.bashrc`

My `~/.bashrc` contains the following (*by default*):

```sh
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

---

### `~/.bash_aliases`

My `~/.bash_aliases` contains the following (*my definition*):

```sh
alias define="curl dict://dict.org/d:$1"
```

---

### Expectation

The `define` in there is the alias so I could use something like the following directly in my shell (terminal):

```sh
define internet
```

While I expect it to look at dict.org and look up definition of internet and display it to me.

For some reason whenever I run it [I get the following](http://paste.debian.net/1130359/) (hosted on paste.debian.net, might disappear in time).

---

I tried sourcing the `~/.bash_aliases` in the `bash` session.

---

### Shell

I'm running `bash` version 5.0.11 on Debian Bullseye (currently testing, and planned major upcoming release).

---

What am I doing wrong with my own alias in `~/.bash_aliases`?

Comment: nope it doesn't . I have edited the question so it makes it more explicit that I am using define just as an alias and not as a function. Hope that makes it clearer above.

Comment: Use a function. Aliases can't take arguments, as you appear to try to do.  The answers to the question that jesse_b linked to explains this in detail.

Comment: So this example given is wrong ? https://read.cash/@Polydot/minimal-web-applications-and-the-curl-command-4bc2f614 @jesse_b

Comment: @shirish: Yes it is.

Comment: can you share how the function would look to fix it in .bashrc or should I make a newer question ?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the alias doesn't take positional parameters like a script or function would.  Additionally your alias in the bashrc is in double quotes so the parameter is expanded immediately (to nothing). So your alias is essentially being set to:

```
alias define="curl dict://dict.org/d:"
```

Even if you properly escaped the parameter either with single quotes or `\` you would still not pass the argument in the way you would think.

`define foo` for example would result in `curl dict://dict.org/d: foo`, to use it that way you would need to set your argument as a shell argument using set:

```
set -- foo; define
```

However a function is definitely the way to go when arguments/options are needed:

```
define () {
    local word=$1
    curl "dict://dict.org/d:$word"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Aliases don't work that way.

The function is more powerful, and can be use:

```
function define(){
  curl "dict://dict.org/d:$1"
}
```

`$1`, is argument 1 of a script or function.